# Vue.js - v-for indicies mixed up?

Tags: vue.js

**What do I have**: components structure

```
<Games> // using v-for - iterate all games
--<Game> // using v-for - iterate all players
----<Player 1>
------<DeleteWithConfirmation>
----<Player 2>
------<DeleteWithConfirmation>
----<Player 3>
------<DeleteWithConfirmation>
----...
```

`<DeleteWithConfirmation>` implementation: two clicks are required for deleting game property.

[image: deleting implementation]

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="incrementDelete"
                v-html="deleteButtonHTML"></button>
        <button v-if="deleteCounter === 1" @click="stopDeleting">
            <i class="undo icon"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'DeleteWithConfirmation',
    data() {
      return {
        deleteCounter: 0
      }
    },
    computed: {
      deleteButtonHTML: function () {
        if (this.deleteCounter === 0)
          return '<i class="trash icon"></i>'
        else
          return 'Are you sure?'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      incrementDelete() {
        this.deleteCounter++
        if (this.deleteCounter === 2) {
          //tell parent component that deleting is confirmed.
          //Parent call AJAX than.
          this.$emit('deletingConfirmed')
          this.stopDeleting()
        }
        else if (this.deleteCounter > 2)
          this.stopDeleting()
      },
      stopDeleting() {
        Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**My problem**: seems like indicies are mixed up:

[image]

Before deleting 4th player was on "Are you sure state" (`deleteCounter === 1`), but after deleting it went to initial state (`deleteCounter === 0`). Seems like 3rd component state haven't updated its `deleteCounter`, but its data (player's name was updated anyway).

After successfull deleting `<Games>` component data is fetched again.

Comment: You don't need a delete counter for achieving this. On the contrary, it makes it hard to understand your code.

Comment: IMO your animations are very distracting

Comment: Try to pass a `:key` within `v-for`

Comment: @GeorgeJempty once upon a time I posted a question with animations as links (not in the question body). My question was edited bu other sir, animations went to the body. Today I put animations to the body, now you say they are distracting. So can you guys clarify the SO question rules for me?

Comment: It's not a "rule", I just find them incredibly distracting.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty so I wish you vote for question deleting, if it's bad for you. I need a help here, not emotions. Sorry for your time by the way.

Comment: @Tarasovych i encourage askers like you that give clarification to their use cases using screenshots or simulations

Comment: What on earth are you talking about "help, not emotions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a delete counter for achieving this. On the contrary, it makes it hard to understand your code. Just use a boolean like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="clickButton"
            <template v-if="confirmation">
                <i class="trash icon"></i>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
                Are you sure?
            </template>
        </button>
        <button v-if="confirmation" @click="confirmation = false">
            <i class="undo icon"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'DeleteWithConfirmation',
    data() {
      return {
        confirmation: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      clickButton() {
        if (!this.confirmation) {
            this.confirmation = true;
        } else {
            this.$emit('deleting-confirmed');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The parent could then be looking e.g. like this:

```
<div class="row" v-if="showButton">
    [...]
    <delete-with-confirmation @deleting-confirmed="showButton = false">
</div>
```

Comment: The answer I found helpful was deleted. Do I have to accept yours now (according to SO rules)? You provide another solution, and that deleted answer was tied up with mine. But you have my vote up, I like your implementation.

Comment: You don't have to accept any question. You can also add the solution, you found helpful, as your own answer to this question, if the original was already deleted and then accept your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

One of the answers was deleted, I wish I could mention the initial author, but I don't remeber his username, so (changed a bit):

```
  incrementDelete() {
    if (this.deleteCounter === 1) { // 1 because there is "post-increment" at the end of the fucntion
      this.deletingProgress = true
      this.$emit('deletingConfirmed')
      this.stopDeleting()
    }
    else if (this.deleteCounter > 1) // 1 because there is "post-increment" at the end of the fucntion
      this.stopDeleting()
    this.deleteCounter++ // "post-increment"
  },
```

[ssc-hrep3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233827/ssc-hrep3) answer is more clean (and lightweight) than mine approach, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53131064/9506712).

Comment: It was me who deleted the answer. Because I saw counter value 2 and greater than 2 and my mind blown up suddenly... BTW, I'm little drunk and thus thought some variations. But glad to see this was helpful. And upvote from me as well.

Comment: But I'm still thinking differently because ===1 condition is matched then > 1 will never match. Ah, was thinking really bad... because there's no return statement. And it's perfectly fine.